# Wordpress plugin options link

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a WordPress Plugin that will list a bunch of records and I need to create an "Edit" link, but I can't figure out how to create this link so it can render via an specific class/method.

Answer (score 1):

The "Options Page" might be what you're looking for:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages

http://ottopress.com/2009/wordpress-settings-api-tutorial/